# How to break out of a while loop?

Tags: conditional-statements, swift2

Using this condition:

```
while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String
```

how may I add another condition based on a decrementing integer:

```
var c=10
while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String && c>0 {
...
c--
...
}
```

The error is:

```
Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `&&` use a `where` clause:

```
while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String where c>0 {
```

Comment: @alecail No, you can't. Even though `&&` would be more intuitive `where` is used to separate the optional binding (check for nil and create a new variable) from the boolean condition. You can use `&&` in the condition.